# How can I insert the last date of modification as a field in a ColdFusion CFIndex of a collection of documents?

Tags: search, solr, coldfusion, document, cfindex

How can the cfindex of a collection be made to include a column containing the **Date Modified** of the various kinds of documents in a specified directory path? Documentation seems to cover this for database collection searches but is silent on file/folder searches.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom column with `cfindex` and populate it with the current date/time whenever a record/document is indexed/updated.

Comment: Thank you Scott-but our application is to be used on several existing documents that will not be modified as well as new ones.  Any other ideas?

Comment: For existing documents, you can probably parse out the 'last modified date' for the file info and use it to populate. In order to sort on this data, you will need to populate it for all records. Personally, I would not sort by 'modified date', just because a record may not have been updated recently, it does not mean it is not the most relevant.

Comment: "...just because a record may not have been updated recently, it does not mean it is not the most relevant."   Ain't that the truth.  That's not the way the internal client sees it though.